# Responsive Images in dynamic div

Tags: javascript, image, html, dynamic

At first I want to show you what I want to create.
[Example!](http://ks-weddings.de/) ! Here you have to go on "Galerien" and now resize the Browser in height or width. You see that the images/divs automatically fits on the container.

There is no problem when you only keep attention on the width, but you have to combine width and height that no image overflow the container. I worked with javascript and i want to create if conditions to prevent the overflow.

It is hard to explain, but i hope the example show my problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look at Bootstrap, it contains a grid system that will work fine with being responsive (smart): http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: that is a good beginning but i only see methods where the width indicates the width of the images. I want that the height of the container also changes the size of the image. In the Link below you can change the browserheight and you see the images get smaller